# How to do Translate Animation Button in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to do a translate (change the position) one button when click another button.
I hope to use translate animation to do that. but I dont have good idea to do that. pls help me with a code.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do this as follows:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
yourbutton.startAnimation(animation);
```

You can take more than one translateanimation object and set their duration so that they will start one after another.

You can also add animationlistener to perform different functions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `TranslateAnimation` class. It's easy to use. Here is an outline:

- Create a `TranslateAnimation` object.
- Set the required attributes like `setFillAfter`, `setAnimationListener`, `setDuration`, `setInterpolater`, etc
- Call `mButton.startAnimation(translate animation obj)` to start the animation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the layout params to change the position of the button when clicked                    other button

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

yourbutton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: How to use this code ..? Is it in inside the onclick listener in main button?

Comment: ya in listener of button who translate the other button who going to translate